# How to measure conversion rate of custom dimensions on Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics

I have added some custom dimensions via dataLayer (GTM). Now I'm creating reports in data studio and want to see unique purchases, revenue and conversion rate of these custom dimensions. I'm using ecommerce to track purchases. When I add one of my custom dimension as dimension and unique purchases as metric to create report, it gives me nothing. What should I do to have the report I want?

Comment: It depends on the scope of your custom dimensions but generally it won't be possible to see unique purchases, revenue and conversion rate. Will transactions, revenue and conversion rate not give you what you need.

The reason for the problem is unique purchases relates to products whereas conversion rate relates to sessions.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [this](https://www.kaushik.net/avinash/hits-sessions-metrics-dimensions-web-analytics/).

You're most likely pairing dimensions and metrics of incompatible scopes together. The scope of of the custom dimension always needs to be "wider" than the scope of the custom metric.